# How can I add jitpack.io as a repository in my build.gradle correctly?

Tags: android, gradle, build-dependencies

I want to use Stepper-Touch github library. For this I have to add jitpack.io in

```
allproject{ 
    repositories{
        [here] 
    }
}
```

in my build.gradle project file. There isn't

```
allproject{...}
```

section, so I added it myself, but i got this error

```
Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by build file 'build.gradle'
```

Then I looked for answer and found that someone says I should remove

```
dependencyResolutionManagement
```

section in my settings.gradle file. I did, but then other dependencies such as constraint layout's, live data's dependencies stopped working.
Help me, how can I fix that all? :(

Answer (score 22):

**As of the 7.X.X gradle build tools.** allprojects is deprecated use of [dependencyResolutionManagement](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:centralized-repository-declaration) is the best practice for declaring repositories in every subproject of your build. Because of this Android projects will no longer generate with allprojects blocks in their project build.gradle files. It will instead generate a dependencyResolutionManagement block in settings.gradle.

You shouldn't experince any issues if you use dependencyResolutionManagement
to achieve the same result as an allprojects block. You can add repositories to the dependencyResolutionManagement repositories block just like you would with an allprojects block like so

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon

        // e.g this is how you would add jitpack
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        // Add any repositories you would be adding to all projects here
    }
}
```

**If you would like to use the old way**

Remove the whole dependencyResolutionManagement block from your settings.gradle so that it looks like

```
rootProject.name = "My Application"
include ':app'
```

Then add the the allproject block to your project build.gradle and make sure to  add all of the dependencies that were in your dependencyResolutionManagement so in our example it would look like

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon

        // e.g this is how you would add jitpack
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        // Add any repositories you would be adding to all projects here
    }
}
```